# How to get the information of Hard deleted records in salesforce

Tags: delete

I need to get the records which are hard deleted from Salesforce. Till now, We used to bring all records from Salesforce and subtract these records from the copy of all the total records of Salesforce in our database, thereby getting all the hard deleted records. 
We are doing this by using an integration tool "IBM Cast Iron", but this method is taking much longer time. Can anyone please explain if he has another way to do the same?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How many records in your Salesforce db now?  How many records in your other database?  How many of each were there when you started using Cast Iron?  Those numbers may tell you why the process is slow now.

Comment: There are different number of records for each object, but it doesn't exceed more than 8 million for a object. In total, there are 40.4 million records in our db and 40.3 million records in Salesforce DB.

Answer (score 3):

- Hard delete means that the records are "really" deleted, once hard delete happens you can not reference or count them.
- A regular delete will put records into the recycle bin, these will stay there for a "period" of time, which is usually 15 days but may be less dependign on variables, see [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm).

In either of the above situations, I would say it may be unreliable to enumerate these on a daily/batch process.
Assuming the requirement here is to record the Accounts that are deleted. Then perhaps other approaches should be considered.

1. An on delete trigger that records the Account information that you wish to save in a custom object. This custom object can then be queried from Cast Iron in a scheduled manner.
2. A real-time callout from Salesforce to a Cast Iron webservice to record the details of the account being deleted.

Essentially here you would need to consider moving the trigger point from "hard delete" to "delete" and you would need to consider how to handle un-deletes, when a user removes an item from the re-cycle bin.